# Erros: division by zero e iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c, c++, visual-studio

Eu estou com problemas ao compilar este codigo, ele me retorna dois erros ao executa-lo:

```
vector<bool> cp( size );

// determine crossover point (randomly)
for( int i = _numberOfCrossoverPoints; i > 0; i-- )
{
    while( 1 )
    {
        int p = rand() % size;
        if( !cp[ p ] )
        {
            cp[ p ] = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

o primeiro erro esta relacionado com a definicao de p, ele diz que ocorre divisao por zero.

o segundo erro esta relacionado com a tentativa de acessar cp com o tal p, ele diz que iterator not dereferencable.

Eu queria entender por que estes erros sao retornados e como soluciona-los.

Answer (score 0):

O erro de divisão por zero em `int p = rand() % size;` ocorrerá se a variável "size" for zero. O segundo erro provavelmente é consequência do primeiro erro.